# Trouble Adding an item to the back of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, double, tail

I’m new to doubly linked lists.  I’m working on a few pieces of code: one function to add an item to the front, another to add an item to the back, and forward and reverse display methods that output the linked list from front to back and back to front, respectively.
I came across an error in my output I’m trying to understand.  It seems my addFront and display functions are working but my addBack is probably where my error is.  I posted what my output is and what it showed be at the bottom of this post.
This is my code thus far.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class doubleLinkedList
{
private:
    class node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
        node(int x)
        {
            data = x;
            next = NULL;
            prev = NULL;
        }
    };
public:
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    int count;



    doubleLinkedList();        //default constructor
    ~doubleLinkedList();      //destructor

    void displayForward();    //display items from front to back
    void displayBackward();   //display items from back to front

    void addFront(int);      //add item to front of linked list
    void addBack(int);       //add item to back of linked list

    int removeFront();       //remove item from front of linked list
    int removeBack();        //remove item from back of linked list
};

//constructor
doubleLinkedList::doubleLinkedList(){
    head = tail = NULL;
    count = 0;
}


//destructor
doubleLinkedList::~doubleLinkedList(){
    node* current = head;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        node* previous = current;
        current = current->next;
        delete previous;
    }

    head = tail = NULL;
    count = 0;
}


//display items in linked list from front to back
void doubleLinkedList::displayForward(){
    node* pCurrent = head;
    while (pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        cout << pCurrent->data << " ";
        pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
    }
    cout << count;
}


//display items in linked list from back to front
void doubleLinkedList::displayBackward(){
    node* pCurrent = tail;
    while (pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        cout <<pCurrent->data << " ";
        pCurrent = pCurrent->prev;
    }
    cout << count;
}


//add item to front of linked list
void doubleLinkedList::addFront(int x){

    node* n = new node(x);
    n->next = head;
    n->prev = NULL;

    if (head != NULL)
        head->prev = n;
        head = n;
        count++;

    if (tail == NULL)
        tail = n;
}

void doubleLinkedList::addBack(int x){
    node* n = new node(x);

    n->next = NULL;
    n->prev = tail;
    tail = n;

    count++;
}
```

////////////////////My Test Code:///////////////////

```
int main()
{
    doubleLinkedList list;

    list.addBack(40);
    list.addBack(50);
    list.addBack(60);
    list.addFront(30);
    list.addFront(20);
    list.addBack(70);
    list.addBack(80);
    list.addFront(10);

    list.displayForward();  //10 20 30 8   (the 8 value is the count/size i'm keeping track of)
        cout << endl;
    list.displayBackward(); //80 70 60 50 40 8
        cout << endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
        }
```

My output should display 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
and                      80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
but instead my displayForward displays the items I added to the Front and my displayBackward displays the items I added to the back.

Comment: Shouldn't you make the tail->next as n before tail = n  , in Addback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to set the old tails next pointer to the new tail. So when going over the list, the next to last node would still be pointing to NULL.

In addition, when adding to the back you weren't checking if head was null, so when adding to the back, you only updated the tail end, and ended up with two separate lists as a result.

So you added 40, 50, 60 to the "end", so the tail pointer was set and updated accordingly, but the head wasn't created until you added **30** to the list, continuing adding elements to the front, the pointers were updated accordingly, but as a result the head and tail were not actually connected.

```
void doubleLinkedList::addBack(int x){       
    node* n = new node(x);

    if (head == nullptr)
        head = n; //this was your main problem!

    if (tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = n;

    n->next = nullptr;
    n->prev = tail;
    tail = n;

    count++;
}
```

Since you seem to be writing C++ code I advise you get used to using nullptr instead of NULL too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus11-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That link is sure to be very useful.

Comment: Okay something is up.  I implemented your code and got the same as my original output.  I'm checking my displays.

Comment: Curious, I'll go over your code again and look for any other possible errors

Comment: Yeah I'm sure.  If it's working for you, then I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Scratch that, It's not correct :P, I'll take another look.

Comment: Didn't notice those spelling errors.  Yeah--older version.

Comment: Aha! Realised you weren't updating head, when you add to the back, there is a chance that there is nothing in the "head" position, in this case you were doing an addBack, but never updated head to the element added.

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I tried something similar earlier but I had an error.  You are a heck of a person for sticking with me.  I really appreciate it.  You were so helpful.